# Profile an async websocket application

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, profiling, python-asyncio

I have been trying to improve one websocket application I wrote based on [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio.html) and [websockets](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/).

In the profiling output I see the most time consuming part is `method 'control' of 'select.kqueue' objects`:
[image]

I do not really know what does this means:

- Does this mean most of time I'm waiting for message?
- Or does this mean I have too many tasks/coroutines that context switching is costing too much time?

Answer (score 1):

It means that asyncio is waiting for new events, most likely for websocket incoming messages for your case.

Consider it as *idle time*.

Comment: ah ok, thanks. So it's the server that is not fast enough, as I have plenty of bandwidth to spare